# Determine indoor location

Tags: android, indoor-positioning-system

I made an Android app that uses the camera to 'see' boxes at crossing. When a user points his/her camera at the box the app draws an arrow at the screen to show which direction the user has to go. At the start the user chooses the room where he/she wants to go.

My next step is to determine whether the user has reached his/her chosen room.

The building has 2 floores.

I had two ideas:

1. Use 3 raspberry pi's and these represent an x, y and z coordinate. 
   The raspberry pi's are going to be connected on the same network as the 
   phone. My concern with this is, i don't think the android phone can receive 3 
   signals from the raspberry pi's and can be connected with the wifi of the 
   building (the 3 raspberry pi's are connected on the network of the building)
2. I could stick some kind of patern on the door of each room and let the user
   scan it. But then the user has to scan each door when walking and each door 
   has a room number on it.
3. Use the accelerometer and gyro of the phone to determine the distance between 
   boxes on crossings. But this is very inaccurate.

I also saw ibeacons, but these things are very pricy.
From my view option 1 seems the best one in terms of scalability. 
The main problem is:
The phone is connected to the wifi of the building. The 3 pi's are connected to the same wifi and need to send signals. Is the phone able to receive all these signals? I don't think is easy/technical possible.

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: There are SDK's available using Bluetooth Low Energy. But the same should be integrated with the buildings that you are targeting. Along with integration with android app that is developed. http://meridianapps.com/sdks/

Comment: @Stallion So i could put bluetooth transmitters in the room. And let the app receive the data to determine the distance to a certain transmitter?

Comment: Exactly. Meridian is just a sample solution. If you could develop similar solution that also will work out.